# Total number of integral solutions for the given second degree equation!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

First, the problem statement : "Consider the equation $x^{2}+y^{2}-3z^{2}-3t^{2}=0$. The total number of integral solutions of this equation in the range of the first 10000 numbers, i.e., $1\leq x,y,z,t\leq10000$ is:
(a.) 200 (b.) 55 (c.) 100 (d.) 1 (e.) None of the above"

I know how to find the number of integral solutions for first degree equations,i.e. form $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+x_{n}=0$ but I am unable to start with this equation.
One observation that I made ( a very obvious one ) is that $x^{2}+y^{2}=3\left( z^{3}+t^{2}\right)$ and thus we can further have $\left(x+y\right)^{2}-3\left(z+t\right)^{2}+6zt-2xy=0$ but this doesn't seem to take me anywhere towards the number of integral solutions.

Any insights or reference that I should refer to solve the above problem?

*The solution given in key is option (e.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no solutions.

Assume the contrary, then by the well-ordering principle there is a solution $(x, y, z, t) $ such that $ x^2 + y^2 $ is minimized. If $ x^2 + y^2 = 3z^2 + 3t^2 $, reducing both sides modulo 3 and noting that the quadratic residues mod 3 are $ 0, 1 $ we have that both $ x $ and $ y $ are divisible by $ 3 $, so we can let $ x = 3x' $ and $ y = 3y' $ to find $ 9x'^2 + 9y'^2 = 3z^2 + 3t^2 $ or $ z^2 + t^2 = 3x'^2 + 3y'^2 $. However, then $ (z, t, x', y') $ is a solution such that $ z^2 + t^2 < x^2 + y^2 $ (assuming that $ x^2 + y^2 > 0 $), contradiction.

The only solution occurs when $ x^2 + y^2 = 0 $ or $ x=y=z=t=0 $, which does not lie in the desired interval.

Comment: Nice Explanation. From what I understood from Wikipedia, Well-Ordering Principle means that in a set of positive integers, there will exist a least element. Thus, we are *assuming* x and y to be least ( since $x+y=3\left(z+t\right)$ ). Then we go ahead and consider them to be multiple of 3. Am I following this right?

Comment: But, I am not able to understand the contradiction here. Since, we have $x^{2}+y^{2}=3\left(z^{2}+t^{2}\right)$ then $x^{2}+y^{2}>z^{2}+t^{2}$ right?

Comment: The contradiction is that we assumed no such solution $ (z, t, x', y') $ existed when we said that $ (x, y, z, t) $ was a solution with minimal positive $ x^2 + y^2 $ (if one exists at all). The well-ordering principle allows us to conclude that there is, in fact, a solution with the smallest value of $ x^2 + y^2 $, which does not hold true for rational numbers, for example. (Consider the set $ \{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots, 1/n, \ldots \} $ - this set has no smallest element.)